# Controller is not a function Angular

Tags: angularjs

I can't get controller working despite being registered

I am defining my controller like below

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  function EntityModulesCtrl(UserManagement, getEntityModules) {
    let ctrl = this;

    console.log('loggging from entityModules ctrl...');
    console.log(getEntityModules);

    ctrl.saveMapping = function () {
      let params = {
        modules: ctrl.selectedModules,
        entity: ctrl.selectedEntity
      };

      UserManagement.saveModuleEntityMapping(params).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }

  angular.module('mean.user_management')
    .controller('EntityModulesCtrl', EntityModulesCtrl);

  EntityModulesCtrl.$inject = ['UserManagement', 'getEntityModules'];
});
```

My route is

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function UserManagement($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'user_management/views/index.html',
      resolve: {
        // dashboardConfig: function () {
        //   var roleType =  localStorage.getItem('roleType');
        // }
      }
    }).state('userManagement circles example', {
      url: '/userManagement/example/:circle',
      templateUrl: 'user_management/views/example.html'
    }).state('dashboard.entityModulesMapping', {
      url: '/userManagement/mapEntityModules',
      templateUrl: 'user_management/views/entityModules.html',
      controller: 'user_management/controllers/EntityModulesCtrl.js',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      resolve: {
        getEntityModules: function (UserManagement) {
          return UserManagement.getEntityModules().then(function (res) {
            console.log("logging from mapEntityModules resolve...");
            console.log(res);
            return res;
          })
        }
      }
    });
  }

  angular.module('mean.user_management')
    .config(UserManagement);

  UserManagement.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

})();
```

I have tried using

```
controller: EntityModulesCtrl
controller: 'EntityModulesCtrl'
controller: "path_to_my_controller_file"
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Your first IIFE is never called. You forgot the parentheses to call it at the end: `()`.

Comment: Exactly. I figured that anyway. Plus changing controller to 'EntityModulesCtrl' will simply work.

Answer (score 0):

Your module should be with dependencies,

```
angular
    .module('mean.user_management',[])
    .config(UserManagement);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script add

```
controller: 'EntityModulesCtrl',
```

in place of
 `controller: 'user_management/controllers/EntityModulesCtrl.js',`

And make sure you add the controllerscript file to your html page.

```
<script src="user_management/controllers/EntityModulesCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure that your controller name must be `EntityModulesCtrl`

Comment: In don't need to add script tag for sure

Comment: check http://plnkr.co/edit/uOW7tUQ2D5P22pBgLyoK?p=info and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501931/assign-multiple-controller-in-stateprovider-state , you can also use controller name there which you have defined already.